# Jenkins Groovy Checker

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins Job DSL in a groovy file in the root of my Git repository. I'd like to setup a PR check on the repository to check the groovy file for any syntax errors or potential issues. I can verify the validity of the file in the Groovy Web Console [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/). I'm sure I'm not the only person running groovy with CI/CD. What's the easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I tried running the groovy file against $JENKINS_URL/script: `curl --data-urlencode "script=$(< /tmp/my.groovy)" $JENKINS_URL/script` but I get this error:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.job(). Apparently it's not aware of Job DSL.

Comment: Jenkins has a [CLI linter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter) which can be used over SSH or HTTP.

Comment: For some reason this is not available in the Docker version of Jenkins. I get a 404 when I attempt to reach it over HTTP and the command is not available in the container.

Comment: Also, `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8888 declaritive-linter
No such command declaritive-linter`

Comment: Also, the CLI linter is only for pipeline validation. If you're groovy file only has jobs in it this will not work.